# How can I use Pandas to read in data that is out of order and sort it?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use Pandas 0.13.0 (and numpy 1.8.0) read in data that is originally out of order. For example, sample data looks like:

```
date_time, weeks, score
9/16/2013 14:05:00,73,160.9358
10/4/2013 13:20:00,75,159.61304
10/20/2013 13:44:00,78,158.06982
11/9/2013 17:18:00,80,156.30614
12/17/2013 14:20:00,86,158.5123664
9/19/2012 14:18:00,21,155.20384
7/7/2012 14:08:00,10,165.56546
7/11/2012 12:23:00,11,162.0381
7/14/2012 11:30:00,11,162.25856
7/17/2012 14:15:00,12,160.71534
```

Note that the dates are out of order, with later dates and weeks first.

When I read in this data, Pandas keeps the original order:

```
In [9]: df=pd.read_csv('2_decimated.csv')
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
             date_time   weeks       score
0  2013-09-16 14:05:00      73  160.935800
1  2013-10-04 13:20:00      75  159.613040
2  2013-10-20 13:44:00      78  158.069820
3  2013-11-09 17:18:00      80  156.306140
4  2013-12-17 14:20:00      86  158.512366
5  2012-09-19 14:18:00      21  155.203840
6  2012-07-07 14:08:00      10  165.565460
7  2012-07-11 12:23:00      11  162.038100
8  2012-07-14 11:30:00      11  162.258560
9  2012-07-17 14:15:00      12  160.715340
```

When I call `df.sort(columns='date_time', inplace=True)`, I get:

```
            date_time   weeks       score
6 2012-07-07 14:08:00      10  165.565460
7 2012-07-11 12:23:00      11  162.038100
8 2012-07-14 11:30:00      11  162.258560
9 2012-07-17 14:15:00      12  160.715340
5 2012-09-19 14:18:00      21  155.203840
0 2013-09-16 14:05:00      73  160.935800
1 2013-10-04 13:20:00      75  159.613040
2 2013-10-20 13:44:00      78  158.069820
3 2013-11-09 17:18:00      80  156.306140
4 2013-12-17 14:20:00      86  158.512366
```

which is close to what I want, but I want date_time to be the index, so this can be time-series data. Calling `df2.set_index('date_time')` appears to do what I want, that is

```
                      weeks       score
date_time                              
2012-07-07 14:08:00      10  165.565460
2012-07-11 12:23:00      11  162.038100
2012-07-14 11:30:00      11  162.258560
2012-07-17 14:15:00      12  160.715340
2012-09-19 14:18:00      21  155.203840
2013-09-16 14:05:00      73  160.935800
2013-10-04 13:20:00      75  159.613040
2013-10-20 13:44:00      78  158.069820
2013-11-09 17:18:00      80  156.306140
2013-12-17 14:20:00      86  158.512366
```

but then calling `df.plot()` shows the same plot as before, and then when I call df again to examine it, df has lost track of the new index and returned to its integer index. Essentially, it seems that the set_index function is not behaving as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

`set_index()` returns a view, so you need to call `df.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)` or alternatively `df = df.set_index('date_time')`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the from_csv method in the DataFrame object:

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame as df

In [2]: df.from_csv('2_decimated.csv')
Out[2]: 
                      weeks       score
date_time                              
2013-09-16 14:05:00      73  160.935800
2013-10-04 13:20:00      75  159.613040
2013-10-20 13:44:00      78  158.069820
2013-11-09 17:18:00      80  156.306140
2013-12-17 14:20:00      86  158.512366
2012-09-19 14:18:00      21  155.203840
2012-07-07 14:08:00      10  165.565460
2012-07-11 12:23:00      11  162.038100
2012-07-14 11:30:00      11  162.258560
2012-07-17 14:15:00      12  160.715340
```

Versus pd.read_csv:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: pd.read_csv('2_decimated.csv')
Out[4]: 
             date_time   weeks       score
0   9/16/2013 14:05:00      73  160.935800
1   10/4/2013 13:20:00      75  159.613040
2  10/20/2013 13:44:00      78  158.069820
3   11/9/2013 17:18:00      80  156.306140
4  12/17/2013 14:20:00      86  158.512366
5   9/19/2012 14:18:00      21  155.203840
6    7/7/2012 14:08:00      10  165.565460
7   7/11/2012 12:23:00      11  162.038100
8   7/14/2012 11:30:00      11  162.258560
9   7/17/2012 14:15:00      12  160.715340
```

After you read the csv via df.from_csv, you can use sort_index() to sort the index:

```
In [5]: df.from_csv('2_decimated.csv').sort_index()
Out[5]: 
                      weeks       score
date_time                              
2012-07-07 14:08:00      10  165.565460
2012-07-11 12:23:00      11  162.038100
2012-07-14 11:30:00      11  162.258560
2012-07-17 14:15:00      12  160.715340
2012-09-19 14:18:00      21  155.203840
2013-09-16 14:05:00      73  160.935800
2013-10-04 13:20:00      75  159.613040
2013-10-20 13:44:00      78  158.069820
2013-11-09 17:18:00      80  156.306140
2013-12-17 14:20:00      86  158.512366
```

That should help you. If I totally misinterpreted your question, let me know.

Comment: I don't recommend importing `DataFrame as df` as `df` is used often as a name for a DataFrame object.